# How to write the MHV amplitude for terms written in a different order?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory

I know that the formula for the MHV amplitude is as follows (using as an example a 5 point amplitude) :

$$A_5\langle 1^-2^- 3^+ 4^+ 5^+\rangle =  \frac{\langle 12\rangle ^3}{\langle  23\rangle\langle  34\rangle\langle  45\rangle\langle  51\rangle} \tag{1}$$

But how do I calculate the amplitude of something similar, but in a different order, like:

$$A_5\langle 1^-4^+ 3^+ 2^- 5^+\rangle \tag{2}$$